# One form submitting two actions based on click in laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I have two routes with two different controllers:

```
Route::post('/save', 'ListingController@store')->name('listings.save.store');
Route::post('/publish','ListingPublishController@store')->name('listings.publish.store');
```

I want to submit the form from the two routes based on the clicked button like this

```
<form action="{{ route('listings.save.store', [$area]) }}" method="post">
  <button class="btn btn-default">save</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default">publish</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't send form to two actions but what you can do  is add name to your button and then check wich button is clicked in you request object then execute your code depend if the first or second button exist in your request

```
if ($request->has('save')) {
   // Add code here
}
```